# PHP file_get_contents add unknown into url

Tags: php, arrays, image, url

I'm getting this error

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   file_get_contents(wp-content/uploads/2013/06/wpid-Mt-ZionlaunchA4poster.jpg<br>)
>   [function.file-get-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   C:\wamp\www\progjet\3\post.php on line 55

As you can see, there is a `<br>` tag at the end of the file name.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($imgf as $imgr){
    echo $imgr;
    $upimg[] = get_img(trim($imgr));
}

function get_img($url){
    file_put_contents(basename($url),file_get_contents($url));
    $path = 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    return $path.'/'. basename($url);
}
```

as you can see I add echo to see the what is going on

and here is the out put

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try `strip_tags($url)`

Comment: You have problem with `$imgr` (and `$imgf`) not with `file_get_contents()`. `echo htmlentities($imgr);` should show you real `$imgr` content.

Answer (score 1):

What is the source of `$imgf`. If it's `POST / GET` data then you need to remove `<br>` from `POST`/`GET` request page.

If you want to remove the `<br>` using `PHP` you can do like this:

```
$imgr = str_replace('<br>', '', $imgr);
```